# DVD re-writable problem?

Tags: dvd-burning

I copied 3.62 GB of data on to a re-writable DVD instead of erasing it. Now there is no data on the disc but it shows used space as 3.62 GB and 690 MB of free space. Now I am unable to erase my disc. What should I do to erase the disc and get the space back?

Comment: On a side note why are you wasting your time with DVD-RWs in this day and age? 4GB USB sticks cost less than a cinema ticket. Regular DVD-Rs cost less than bubblegum.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't supposed to format a DVD-RW. Use something like [CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/)'s erase function:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another free alternative:

[ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/)

[image: ImgBurn]

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to install additional software, use **[InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/)** Portable.

Go to **Actions** >  **Erase/Format Disc...**

Answer (score 1):

As stated elsewhere, you need to erase the DVD-RW before using it again. I have a very simple low profile program I use called Active@DVD Eraser located here:http://www.ntfs.com/dvd_eraser.htm